# app.yaml isn't updated when I deploy (Google App Engine, Java)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, yaml

This is what I put in the `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: java8
service: 'scheduler'
inbound_services:
- warmup
derived_file_type:
- java_precompiled
threadsafe: True
auto_id_policy: default
api_version: '1.0'
handlers:
- url: (/.*)
  static_files: __static__\1
  upload: __NOT_USED__
  require_matching_file: True
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /.*/
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /_ah/.*
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /cron/v1/simulations
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 1
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
```

And when it's deployed, on GCP its config looks like this:

```
runtime: java8
api_version: '1.0'
env: standard
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1
inbound_services:
  - warmup
handlers:
  - url: '(/.*)'
    application_readable: false
    static_files: "__static__\\1"
    require_matching_file: true
    upload: __NOT_USED__
  - url: /
    script: unused
  - url: '/.*/'
    script: unused
  - url: '/_ah/.*'
    script: unused
  - url: /cron/v1/simulations
    script: unused
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
```

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

I did try changing `min_num_instances: 1` and `max_num_instances: 2` to `min_idle_instances: 1` `max_idle_instances: 2`, with no different result.

It's creating way more instances than I need, and the billing sum has gone up threefold since I noticed these changes. Very confusing.

Comment: Note that you're mixing flexible env specific configs (`resources`, for example) in your standard env `app.yaml`. At best they will be just ignored. This *might* be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45842772/4495081

Comment: That is also true, and yes they were just ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simple solution was that it wasn't the app.yaml I should edit for the standard env., it was the appengine-web.xml.

Now I've got full control again, it seems!

I also deleted old services (which I thought wasn't running, because it looked like they were not on? Seeing as they were shown as 0%...). Sometimes GAE doesn't scale down by itself, I learned.